# Growth hormone and training at night

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training

Given this: http://www.precisionnutrition.com/all-about-gh

and specifically the graphic there, is it theoretically possible that training hard / eg lifting intensely, at night takes advantage of peak GH periods...? Or is it that chances are this graph is premised on someone with 'normal' circadian rhythms... Ie someone training at 2am may well have cycles such that GH secretions peaks 'later' than 2am...

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

No just the opposite.  The article is clearly saying that there is a link that during our heavy sleep our bodies use GH to repair ourselves.  What you are proposing is getting less sleep or less quality of sleep which would then reduce the amount of GH secreted to our body.

Also the GH is a repair mechanism (mainly).  It can be enhanced due to vigorous/intense activities, sleep, and drugs.

By working out at 2 AM you would be getting less sleep and I would guess from most people, not have the same intensity you could have during normal waking hours, therefore I would expect a decrease in GH levels.

Also there is no correlation between GH levels and training periods, other than you need high GH levels after training for your body to repair.